# could someone help out fixing the follow mysql syntax error

Tags: mysql, pdo

friends my search query below i wish to show results whose "column name" connection!='0' i did like this (NOT connection = '0' OR connection IS NULL)

but somehow i am getting the following error

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(NOT connection
>   = 0; OR connection IS NULL) ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT ? OFFSET ?' at line 1'

here is my code

```
foreach($search_fields as $field)
{
    if(isset($_GET[$field]) && $_GET[$field] != 'All') 
    {
        $and_clause[] = "`$field` = :$field";
        $params[] = array(":$field",$_GET[$field],PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }
}

$where_clause = '';
if(!empty($and_clause))
{
    $where_clause = "WHERE (NOT connection = '0' OR connection IS NULL) " . implode(' AND ', $and_clause);
}

$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table $where_clause";

if(empty($params))
{
    $stmt = $db->query($query);
}
else
{
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    foreach($params as $param)
    {
        $stmt->bindValue($param[0],$param[1],$param[2]);
    }
    $stmt->execute();
}

$total = $stmt->fetchColumn();

$pages = ceil($total / $records_per_page);

$page = min($pages, filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'page', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array(
'options' => array(
'default'   => 1,
'min_range' => 1,
),
)));

$offset = ($page - 1)  * $records_per_page; 

$params[] = array(':records_per_page',$records_per_page, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$params[] = array(':offset',$offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);

$query = "SELECT * FROM table $where_clause (NOT connection = '0' OR connection IS NULL)  ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT :records_per_page OFFSET :offset";
```

Comment: `WHERE (connection <> '0'`

Comment: still getting error when i hit the submit button upon dropdown selection

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND (connection <> '0') ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT ? OFFSET ?' at line 1'

Comment: That looks like your 2nd select and values for your limit and offset appear to be missing.

Comment: How could this be sorted? been trying all day but no solution :(

Comment: This line works now but when i do a search error throws up | $query = "SELECT * FROM table$where_clause WHERE connection !='0' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT :records_per_page OFFSET :offset";

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: sorted at last :)

Answer (score 0):

This was the line :D

```
 $and_clause[] = "`$field` = :$field AND connection !='0'";
```

problem solved.